# How to configure webhooks.config?

Tags: jenkins, gerrit

I am trying to integrate Gerrit to Jenkins. For this, I am trying to use Gerrit Code Review plugin of Jenkins but I don't know how to arrange webhooks.config properly.

I want to propogate all events to related Jenkins job. So I write webhooks.config like:

```
    [remote "Jenkins"]
      url = http://localhost:8080/job/name_of_jenkins_job
      maxTries = 3
      sslVerify = false
```

But after this arrangement, changes not appear in Jenkins job.
I have doubt with URL. Is any spesific thing required in URL line of webhooks.config ?

Answer (score 0):

I followed this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67346903/110214

For the url I just used a global webhook path for jenkins, which is added together with the gerrit plugin.

```
[remote "jenkins"]
  url = http://jenkins.domain.tld:8081/gerrit-webhook
```