# How to Configure Gerrit Webhooks for gerrit events

Tags: git, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, gerrit

I am trying to perform some actions on gerrit events

1. When a new repo is added/created.
2. When a new patch-set is created.
3. When a change is merged into a specific branch.

The idea is to get event on API endpoint when any of the above happens in any repository.

I have gerrit 3.1.3 installation running on Amazon Linux ec2 instance, and a node server (with open API endpoints) on another similar EC2 Machine. In gerrit config I have added the following lines:

```
[plugin "webhooks"]
    connectionTimeout = 3000
    socketTimeout = 2500
    maxTries = 300
    retryInterval = 2000
    threadPoolSize = 3
[remote "wh_projectCreated"]
        url = http://17.233.138.23:8080/gereve
        maxTries = 1
        sslVerify = false
        event = patchset-created
```

I have checked `webhooks` and `hooks` plugins are both installed in gerrit installation.
Now, I couldn't find a proper blog post which tells how to configure and get gerrit events to be received on webhooks.

What do I need to do more, great help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found the solution, will write down precisely:

1. In a Folder clone the `All-Projects` repo (with admin url). `git clone "http://admin@<gerrit-address>-:<gerrit-port>/a/All-Projects"`.
2. `cd All-Projects/`
3. `git fetch origin refs/meta/config:refs/remotes/origin/meta/config`
4. `git checkout meta/config`
5. In the root of directory `All-Projects`, create a file named `webhooks.config`.
6. Modify the contents below:

```
[remote "changemerged"]
  url = http://<webhook-api>:8081/change-merged
  event = change-merged
  
[remote "project_created"]
  url = http://<webhook-api>:8081/create-jenkins-project
  event = project-created
```

see [gerrit-events](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/cmd-stream-events.html).

7. Add and commit the change: `git commit -am "Add webhooks config file"`
8. And check in `git push origin meta/config:meta/config`

and that's it we are done!

(Upvote if you found this helpful)

Comment: Thanks for sharing! Just a nit, If you want to compress point 3 and 4 together you could do: `git fetch origin refs/meta/config && git checkout FETCH_HEAD`

Comment: This didn't work for me - I did this instead; checkout refs/meta/config into local branch meta/config: `3. git fetch origin refs/meta/config:meta/config` then push local branch meta/config into remote refs/meta/config: `8. git push origin meta/config:refs/meta/config`

Comment: how to debug it if I use a common gerrit instance and what data model it is sent out

Answer (score 4):

You can send a PUT HTTP request to update the webhooks.config file:

```
curl --location --request PUT '[Gerrit-Site]/a/config/server/webhooks~projects/All-Projects/remotes/[Remote-Name]' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic aWR...' \
--data-raw '{
    "url" : "https://adbf...43.ngrok.io/api/v1/webhook/e527d4d7-49e5-4699-b780-5b5c8420dc0f",
    "max_tries" : 3,
    "ssl_verify": false,
    "connection_timeout": 10000
```

- Make sure to update the webhooks plugin global configuration in gerrit.config.
- Make sure to include '/a/' in the URL for authenticated requests.

References:

- [Gerrit webhooks REST API](https://github.com/GerritCodeReview/plugins_webhooks/blob/master/src/main/resources/Documentation/rest-api-config.md)
- [Gerrit configuration](https://gerrit-staging.phx.ovirt.org/plugins/webhooks/Documentation/config.md)