# Jira cloud integration with Gerrit

Tags: cloud, jira, gerrit

I am trying to integrate Gerrit with Jira cloud using *its-jira plugin* in Gerrit. Can anyone suggest on how to proceed on this integration part.

I tried adding the username and API token of jira cloud in the *gerrit.config* file. But its throwing error as the jira issue-id is not existing. But the ticket is there in jira.

Expecting:
Once any commit is done along with the jira ticket id, then the commit message should be visible in the respective jira ticket comment section.

Answer (score 0):

The setup needs to be done in the repository, inside the project.config file inside the refs/meta/config branch.

To access this specific branch locally do the following:

- Clone the desired repository testrepo.
- Change into the checked out folder testrepo.
- git fetch origin refs/meta/config:refs/remotes/origin/meta/config
- git checkout meta/config (if this doesnt work, try git checkout origin/meta/config)
- Modify the file project.config.
- Add and commit the change: git commit -am "Update project config file"
- Push to the server: git push origin meta/config:meta/config

If you want to create a change request, use this: git push origin meta/config:refs/for/refs/meta/config
(might have to use git push origin HEAD:refs/for/refs/meta/config)

The changes specific to the JIRA integration looks like this:

```
[plugin "its-jira"]
  enabled = true
  branch = refs/heads/master
  branch = ^refs/heads/release/.*
```

Here the plugin would only be applied to the master  branches and any release/  branches, and no others. So only INCLUSIONS can be specified, but NO EXCLUSIONS!

Note: You should create a system user for gerrit,add that user eg.GERRIT_JIRA user to the Jira space as developer role.

Check also [How to Configure Gerrit Webhooks for gerrit events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65575218/how-to-configure-gerrit-webhooks-for-gerrit-event)

Also Check this page https://community.wandisco.com/s/article/Guide-to-ITS-Jira-plugin-with-Gerrit